# Is the data in xml/html form stored temporarily?

Tags: html, forms, browser

Eg: If data is input into HTML forms' fields, before pressing the 'Submit/Enter', where is the data being stored. Is the data input by a keyboard stored in some file/ some data structure. Like before I submitted this post, where were these sentences temporarily stored?

Comment: Wherever the developer of the browser wants to store it.

Comment: In your computers memory...like all other information available in running applications

Comment: If I have a mobile application, that requires users to enter data into fields, where am I going to store the data while it is being input, before being sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

There may be several answers possible to that question.

- If the browser developer wants to store them, (s)he will do so.
- If your question is about stackoverflow specifically, then there is something like a draft. Many of webforms now have a draft saving feature these days with them. So that a copy of it is saved for later editing/viewing.

Mostly, all you do is kept as event in the event logger(microsoft) and maybe there's something similar in Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

The text in your inputs is stored in your memory when you haven't submitted the form. Inputs allow the user to interact through type or selections, the user interaction does not do live modification of the DOM. So the text lives in memory until you commit/submit the page.

Similar to when you make a new text file, type in it and you haven't saved it yet.

On submit, whatever server side language handles the request and makes the data you enter available in a super global $_POST or $_GET in php

Answer (score 0):

When you type into a form field, the data is stored within the browser itself (most likely just within memory).

When you type into a text input, you're essentially setting the `value` attribute of that HTML `<input>` tag. You can use a language like JavaScript to access this data if you want to manipulate it on-the-fly.

Comment: Where does the information stored? Is it in a temp folder of windows or some other file in the browser's directory?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the information is stored within the browser itself, probably in memory. Each browser will deal with it in its own way. (The same would be true of a mobile app component such as UIWebView for iOS.) There's no way of finding out where it is located or of gaining access to it. If you need access to the data you need to use JavaScript to interrogate the form inputs as I suggested. I think the bigger question is Why do you need access to it? Perhaps there's a different question that needs answering.